# Concatenate Strings of Custom Object Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am communicating with a web service which returns a response. The response can have errors collection. I need to iterate through the collection and concatenate all the reasons. Here is the code:

```
var errorText = "";

for ( var i = 0; i < response.errors.count; i++ ) {
    errorText += response.errors[i].reason; 
}
```

This works! But I am thinking there has to be a better compact way.

Comment: @Hexaholic This is a perfectly answerable specific programming question, as such I find it perfectly on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A foreach?

```
var errorText = "";
response.errors.forEach(function(element) {
    errorText += element.reason;
});
```

Edit:  Some clarification.

A foreach is better than a for loop especially because JavaScript does not enforce contiguous elements.

Assuming your array is as such:  `{1, 2, 3, undefined, 4, 5, 6, undefined, 7}`

A `for` loop would obviously iterate including the undefined values, where a `forEach` would not.

Note, if you're working with an object instead of an array, a `forEach` will not work.  You will instead need:

```
var errorText = "";
Object.keys(response.errors).forEach(function(key) {
    errorText += response.errors[key];
});
```

This is much better than `for` or `for ... in` when working with Objects.  however in this case I'm assuming it's an array, but I can't know for sure without more info.

Comment: i would add a space between.

Answer (score 6):

Use [**Array.prototype.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**Array.prototype.join**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var response = {
  errors: [{
    reason: 'invalid username'
  }, {
    reason: 'invalid password'
  }, {
    reason: 'required field'
  }]
};
var errorText = response.errors.map(function(errorObject) {
  return errorObject.reason;
}).join('');

/*with shorter ES6 syntax
var errorText = response.errors.map(errorObject => errorObject.reason).join('');
*/

console.log(errorText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fun with one-liners and ES6

```
const errorText = response.errors.map(err => err.reason).join(" ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ya26m2dq/1/

Comment: your answer best